# delete operation issue in jquery modal confirmation dialog box in masterpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net

hi im developing a project using masterpage in asp.net

my scenario is i want to select item in dropdown list the selected item should be deleted using modal confirmation box.....

my problem is i want to delete the selected item in dropdown when i click the delete button in modal confirmation box

here's is my code
**Code:**

```
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {

             $("#<%=btndlt.ClientID%>").click(function (e) 

              {
               if ($("#<%=ddlbus.ClientID%>").val() == "") {

                   e.preventDefault();

                   $("#jqselect").dialog();
                 }
               else {



                   $("#jqdialog").dialog({
                       autoopen:false,
                       modal: true,
                       resizable: false,
                       draggable: false,
                       buttons: {
                           "Delete all items": function () {   
                               //....problem goes here need solution.//     
                           },
                           Cancel: function () {
                               $(this).dialog("close");
                               return false;
                           }
                       }
              });

                 }

             });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well but here is an idea:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=btndlt.ClientID%>").click(function (e){
        var $this = $(this); // is this the target item?

        if ($("#<%=ddlbus.ClientID%>").val() == "") {
           e.preventDefault();
           $("#jqselect").dialog();
        }
        else {
            $("#jqdialog").dialog({
                autoopen:false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'delete all items',
                    click: function(){
                        $this.remove();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'cancel',
                    click: function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return false;
                    }
                }];
            });
        }
    });
});
```